# Leave only one tag from two: [networking] vs [network-programming]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Currently on SO we have two very similar tags:

- [networking](/questions/tagged/networking) (7677)
- [network-programming](/questions/tagged/network-programming) (2639)

Both are network and network programming related, have similar wiki entries.

Don't we want to merge them and make synonyms? I vote for `networking` because `x-programming` on programming site is a tautology.

Comment: Downvoters, be so kind as to comment. Do you like to choose between two almost equal tags? I don't

Answer (score 5):

I tend to agree that [network-programming](/questions/tagged/network-programming) needs to be merged into something else; the "programming" affix should be *assumed* for most tags on Stack Overflow. (c#*-programming*, dom*-programming*, iphone*-programming*, boat*-programming*...)

If "networking" is ambiguous (and it is), then reverse the synonym already present: networking->network (and then network-programming->network).

Then we'd have [social-networking](/questions/tagged/social-networking) and [network](/questions/tagged/network). *Should* be distinct enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way would be to treat this as the [2012 retag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) and mark [networking](/questions/tagged/networking) as not to be used and migrate the questions to [network-programming](/questions/tagged/network-programming) as a significant number of the questions are not programming and shpould be closed as off topic e.g. from the first eight questions currently shown for that tag questions

- [Networking: TNV Computer network traffic visualization tool crashed
  running on java netbean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561024/networking-tnv-computer-network-traffic-visualization-tool-crashed-running-on-j)
- [Is it possible to share an Ethernet connection to a secure wireless
  network in OS X on a MacBook Pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554168/is-it-possible-to-share-an-ethernet-connection-to-a-secure-wireless-network-in-o)
- [Multiple IPs per domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553726/multiple-ips-per-domain)

Comment: I agree, it should be retagged `network-programming` and `networking` should go away.

Comment: Added to the cleanup.

Comment: up to the community but agree you query is not representative :)

Comment: @abatishchev That post is welcome to feedback on all the tags listed.  At 7K+ questions, I don't think that it's going to be a tag anyone takes up soon.  Also, there's a request for opinions as well as a repeat of the above suggestion, as well as some other info.

Comment: @casperOne: That was a comment to Mark regarding 3 from 8 of 7,6k. Anyway thanks for taking care about my request.